# What do I miss (while-loop)?

Tags: bash

I try to built a Programm where I can create Text-Files and folders. The user can type in i.a. the directory. To check if the given path exits I created a while-loop but it doesn’t work.
My question is where are my errors and how can I fix them.

```
while [[ test -e $path == false]] 
do echo “type in a valid path”
read -r path
done
```

Error:

```
./Create: line 28: conditional binary operator expected
./Create: line 28: syntax error near `e'
./Create: line 28: `while [[ test -e $path == false ]]'
```

Comment: `while ! test -e "${path}“; do ...` also you need to init path for first iteration

Comment: Thanks for the great help!

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`), then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: @alonewolf : The word _test_ does not make sense, nor does the _== false_ part.  Read the section titled _CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS_  in the bash man page. You will see in particular, that `-e` is an unary operator, so a left hand side argument does not make sense.

Answer (score 4):

I found a couple of issues:

1. You should use `[[` or `test`, but not both
2. `false` is not a constant in bash

The fix:

```
while [[ ! -e $path ]]
do
    ....
done
```